# Exception raised in both try and except .

Tags: python, finally, try-except

```
def FancyDivide(list_of_numbers, index):
try:
    try:
        raise Exception("0")
    finally:
        denom = list_of_numbers[index]
        for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
            list_of_numbers[i] /= denom
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

When function is called I got the following output.

```
FancyDivide([0, 2, 4], 0)
integer division or modulo by zero
```

In the try code an exception is raised. In finally also there is an exception .Why is it so that exception in the finally was caught not the exception in the try.

Comment: It was caught.  Then you printed it.

Comment: I am asking why exception in try block was not caught. If it was caught then the last statement prints 0 not 'integer division or modulo by zero'

Comment: thats what I am asking.Why 0 is not printed.

Comment: Your example is somewhat hard to follow.  Consider narrowing it down to something like `try: try: raise Exception("first"); finally: raise Exception("second"); except Exception as e: print(e);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions)

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not. **When an exception has occurred in the try clause and has not been handled by an except clause (or it has occurred in a except or else clause), *it is re-raised after the finally clause has been executed.***

(Emphasis mine)

As given, the exception - `Exception("0")` would have only been raised again after completing the `finally` block. But because an exception occured in the `finally` block, it was raised instead of the `Exception("0")` .